# How to develop auto logout using Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have to add functionality on the App.xaml.cs to get this to work. I added functionality on OnStart but now it logs me out of the app over and over again intermittently. What do I need to do to get it to stop doing this based on my code below. Or is there a problem at all with my code. Here is my latest code:

```
  namespace MyApp
  {
   public partial class App : Application
  {
    DateTime _sessionStart;

    public App()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

        DatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(new DatabaseService());

        HttpManager = new HttpManager(new HTTPService());

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        _sessionStart = DateTime.Now;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), () =>
        {
            // Check if 24 hours has elapsed
            if (DateTime.Now > _sessionStart.AddHours(24))
            {
                //logout
                 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
            }

            return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
        });


    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to log the user out, then they likely have some sort of token or session that is holding the fact that they're currently authenticated in login. With many types of tokens (like JWT) you can specify an expiration date so that the token will only last for so long. 
In general the frontend should present a new request and the backend should validate that the client is still active. If not, log the client out by rejecting their authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try tracking the idle time (time without touches in the app) by registering a custom application on Main. See example below

Set `TimeoutInSeconds` value to your desired interval (ex 24 hours)

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main (args, "MYCUSTOMAPP", "AppDelegate");
    }
}

[Register ("MYCUSTOMAPP")]
public class MYCUSTOMAPP : UIApplication
{ 
    const int TimeoutInSeconds = 1800; // 30 minutes
    NSTimer idleTimer;

    public override void SendEvent (UIEvent uievent)
    {
        base.SendEvent (uievent);

        if (idleTimer == null)
            ResetTimer ();
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;
        if (allTouches != null && allTouches.Count > 0 && ((UITouch)allTouches.First ()).Phase == UITouchPhase.Began)
            ResetTimer ();
    }

    void ResetTimer ()
    {
        if (idleTimer != null)
            idleTimer.Invalidate ();

        idleTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, TimeoutInSeconds), (t) => TimerExceeded());

    }

    void  TimerExceeded ()
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName ("TimeoutNotification", null);
    }
}
```

Add an observer to you view controller to log them out

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("TimeoutNotification"), handleInactivityNotification);
    }

    public void handleInactivityNotification(NSNotification notification)
    {
        //Return to login page (Root view controller)
        this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
    }
```

Comment: So would this custom app and view controller go in the Main.xaml page?

Comment: Is this a Xamarin.Forms application or Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: Xamarin.iOS application

Comment: @mlynn Main.xaml is for Xamarin.Froms , Main.cs is for Xamarin.iOS. Can you clarify so i can help you further ?

Comment: Yes it is a Main.cs for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: OK , custom app should go on the Main.cs , and you can register the observer and the handler on your login screen. Also corrected a typo on the NSNotificationCenter observer registration code

Comment: Also for the view controller code, what controller is that going on? Login page?

Comment: Yes you can place that on the Login screen

Comment: Hi if you are still around. I'm going to have to add this to the App.xaml.cs code. I updated my original post with the new code. The problem I'm having when testing is that it application is getting logged time & again after login(Intermittent Issue). Application should not get logged out before the estimated time interval.

Comment: Can you open another post about this , since its a different issue and it looks like a Xamarin.Forms application rather than Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android