# Xamarin Forms navigate to Login Page after certain time without doing anything

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, timer, xamarin.android

what I want is that after a certain time of not using the app the user automatically loggs out.
Logout is basically a navigation to the LoginPage.
How can I accomplish that? Do I need a Timer and set it back every single time I do something?

Thank you

Kai

Comment: That's what I would do. Timer Stop/Start. Make a static method somewhere, so you can call it from anywhere. Make custom subclasses of all the controls you use, and add that call in overrides where needed. I know that is a lot of places to have to customize. Maybe you can make a custom touch listenener, and cause your app to use that everywhere? Not sure how.

Comment: [This forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bbf56c5-1178-4578-a0f8-9c4535beb6f9/perform-some-action-when-no-user-interaction?forum=xamarinforms) has some suggestions.

Comment: Also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55542233/199364).